# How to view the column data based on another column data in the same table?

Tags: sql, oracle

SQL> select employeeid, fname, salary, supervisor  from employee;

```
EMPLOYEEID FNAME               SALARY SUPERVISOR
---------- --------------- ---------- ----------
       111 Heng                265000
       246 Ananda              150000        111
       231 Nagapan              85000        246
       123 Vellu               105000        111
       443 Fatimah              80000        111
       433 Amin                 66500        443
       323 Kamuingat            76500        443
       200 Jing                 24500        135
       135 Hong                 45000        111
       322 Derek                75000        123
       128 Dong                 38000        135
       248 Fatt                 30000        135
```

I want the supervisor column view as the supervisor name. the name already exists in the fname. How to make the supervisor name view based on the id in the employeeid column?

Comment: There's not enough information here to answer. Where is the supervisor's name stored? If supervisors are stored within the employees table, then you need a self join.

Comment: You will need to perform what is called  a "Join". Assuming that Supervisor data is in the Employee Table, the operation is then called a "self-join" see: https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2016/03/27/self-join-explain-example-interview-question-week-064/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want something like this:

```
select e.employeeid, e.fname, e.salary, s.fname
from employee e join employee s on (e.supervisor = s.employeeid)
```

You are joining the employee table to itself using the supervisor column as the id column. If that doesn't make sense, look up joins in the docs.

Comment: tq i dont know we can self join the table. thanks for let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to `self join using outer join` otherwise the first record where the supervisor is null will be omitted from the result.

So I guess following is the query which you should try:

```
select e.employeeid, e.fname, e.salary, s.fname
from employee e left join employee s on (e.supervisor = s.employeeid)
```

Note that I have done **left join**.

Cheers!!